# How can I look into nohup file while the program is still running?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, nohup

I was using

```
nohup ./program_name &
```

to run my program, program_name prints out some values and status of the running process including how much percentage the program has finished, but since I'm running it using nohup so I can't see how close my program to finish is, is there anyway I can still get that information?

Comment: Rather than using `nohup`, perhaps you should investigate using `screen` or `tmux` - that way you don't have to redirect the output to a file and deal with the buffering delay involved...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have to Just open `nohup.out` to see output. Probably you want

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

for streaming output

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps adjust your nohup command line to capture all output to a file:

`nohup ./program_name > /tmp/programName.log 2>&1 &`

Then, you can monitor `programName.log` using tail:

`tail -f /tmp/programName.log`

Answer (score 0):

Put the below command in current terminal where the program is running

jobs command used to lists the jobs that you are running in the background and in the foreground

```
   jobs -l
```

[6]+  6069 Running                 nohup perl test1.pl &

[6]+  6069 Done                    nohup perl test1.pl